# OpenVPN client config: Route command fails

Tags: ubuntu, gnome3, openvpn, networkmanager

I want to connect to my company's VPN server, so I can access work resources.

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 15.04, and I've been given an `ovpn`-file. I installed OpenVPN and run `sudo openvpn --config ~/Downloads/client.ovpn` (where `~/Downloads/client.ovpn` is the path to the downloaded company OpenVPN-configuration). This seemed to connect me, but I couldn't access any of the company resources through my browser.

Puzzled, I looked at the output of the openvpn-command, and found this:

```
ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
```

After some Googling, I've found people with the same issue, but they seem to have access to the VPN-server in question, and adds information to that config. As it is a company VPN, I want to make sure there's nothing I can do, before I contact the IT department.

Because I know that the Network Manager of Ubuntu has support for VPN, and I tried to use it, but it couldn't load my `ovpn`-file directly. That's why I went with OpenVPN, but it may be that the Network Manager is in the way? Any suggestions?

- [Complete output of the OpenVPN-command](http://pastebin.com/D6TRGymF)
- [ifconfig](http://pastebin.com/knUNaSAn)
- [route -n](http://pastebin.com/HS5eV8yn)

Comment: If you add the route manually while the tunnel is still up? Any output from tcpdump on the vpn-interface after connection establishment?

Comment: You need to add much more information. `ifconfig` of the VPN-device, and the real ethX, `route -n`, copy openvpn-output. Edit out "secrets".

Comment: Sorry for not keeping up with this, and thanks for looking at it. @AlexStragies Added the requested info. I do not know how to add the route manually, as I'm unsure of which route it's even talking about. Seems two of my routes are not tunneled (`route -n`)?

Comment: It would seem (from a short glance), that your local network is 192.168.1.X, and that your company is trying to push a route through openvpn for that network, leading to a conflict. Try commenting the line in your config starting with "route ... 192.168.1.0". Or renumber your home LAN

Comment: @AlexStragies Hm, that may be it, but there's no `route` in the `client.ovpn`-file.